# Installed "Windows Wireless Drivers" but Cannot launch it. It does not show up in the Dash Search

Tags: wireless, drivers, unity-dash

Very new to Linux and Ubuntu.
After some issues getting the new 14.04 installation not to freeze due to my gpu, I was able to poke around here for answers and all is up and running well now.

I need to install a wireless driver for my Wireless USB Adapter and found a very helpful YouTube video that shows  you to download this "Windows Wireless Drivers" ndiswrapper program and how to install the driver.

Only problem is I installed it, it indicates its been installed in the Software Center. But when I search using the dash it doesnt come up (as it does quite readily in the video).

I tried installing other programs to make sure this wasnt a widespread issue, and all those programs come up just fine. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. Still no result to launch the program.

Any reason that it wouldn't come up?

Comment: run sudo ndisgtk  in termainl. Might work.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ndiswrapper in many years, but here's what I found:

```
$ apt-cache search ndiswrapper
...
ndisgtk - graphical frontend for ndiswrapper (installation of Windows WiFi drivers)
```

That is probably the package you need.

If that is the package you installed, look for the executable by running:

```bsh
dpkg -L ndisgtk | grep /usr/bin
```

Then run `/usr/bin/whatever`.